# JS: function pushing value into parametred localStorage.address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I try to create a `if ... then...` function to push objects into wished localStorage. However, the simple function to push objects into the wished localStorage fails. In localStorage.mydata the parameter mydata is considered as a variable.

**JS such:**

```
function pushToLocalStorage(mydata, num) {
   localStorage.mydata = num ;
}
pushToLocalStorage("data", 42);
pushToLocalStorage("data2.name", "Hello!");
```

But I indeed wish to push my values into *localStorage**.data*** and *localStorage**.data2.name**.*

**How to make a function pushing input into a specified localStorage.specificName ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `localStorage.mydata` by localStorage**[mydata]** and it works:

```
function pushToLocalStorage(mydata, num) {
    localStorage[mydata] = num ;
}
pushToLocalStorage("data", 42)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wazHr/1/

Comment: @Hugoplz, because you are changing a property keyed dynamically, you should use `obj[prop]` syntax instead of `obj.prop`.

Comment: @alias: A bit complex for new JS user, but Thanks!

Comment: `localStorage.mydata` would access the property named `myData`! If you use `localStorage[xxx]`, it returns the property named after the result of the expression `xxx` in this case, therefore `localStorage[myData]` is right.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
function pushToLocalStorage(mydata, num) {
    localStorage.setItem(mydata, num);
}
```

Retrieve with `localStorage.getItem(mydata);` <--- Replace mydata with key name.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wazHr/3/

Also, if you haven't already, be sure to check if the browser even supports localStorage.

Comment: Does it works for you ? Elegant code, but doesn't work on my side. http://jsfiddle.net/wazHr/2/

Comment: @Hugolpz -- Forgot to add the `.setItem`

Comment: Thanks! I keep this (.setItem/.getItem) in mind for later use. Could be handy!

Comment: This is part of the [HTML5 web storage specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-setitem). This method throw an exception if value can't be set, helful for debugging.